# Reference to the Main Form whilst trying to Serialize objects in C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a button on my main form which calls a method to serialize some objects to disk.  I am trying to add these objects to an ArrayList and then serialize them using a BinaryFormatter and a FileStream.

```
   public void SerializeGAToDisk(string GenAlgName)
    {
        // Let's make a list that includes all the objects we 
        // need to store a GA instance
        ArrayList GAContents = new ArrayList();
        // Structure and info for a GA
        GAContents.Add(GenAlgInstances[GenAlgName]);  
        // There may be several running GA's
        GAContents.Add(RunningGAs[GenAlgName]);  

        using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(GenAlgName + ".ga", 
            FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            BinaryFormatter binFormat = new BinaryFormatter();
            binFormat.Serialize(fStream, GAContents);
        }
    }
```

When running the above code I get the following exception:

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was unhandled
  Message=Type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' in Assembly 'GeneticAlgApp, Version=1.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

**So that means that somewhere in the objects I'm trying to save there must be a reference to the main form.  The only possible references I can see are 3 delegates which all point to methods in the main form code.  Do delegates get serialized as well?  I can't seem to apply the `[NonSerialized]` attribute to them.**

Is there anything else I might be missing?  Even better, is there a quick method to find the reference(s) that are causing the problem?

**UPDATE:**

Well I got my code to work by saving the delegates into temporary variables and then setting them to null before serialization.  I then set them back to the original values afterwards.  It seems like there should be a better way to do this.  Any comments please?

**ANSWER:**

I couldn't figure out a way to stop my delegates from being serialized other than setting them to null before serializing, however I think the best solution was to **change my code to use events instead**.  As Mark Gravell stated in his answer events can be omitted from serialization by marking them with the `[field:Nonserialized]` attribute.  Problem solved.  Nobody actually suggested this but I guess Mark's answer was the closest.

Comment: What type of objects you want to serialize?

Comment: They are custom objects that represent state information and data for a genetic algorithm.  Too large to post here

Answer (score 2):

This almost always means that you've subscribed to an event from the form. Yes, delegate fields are serialized by default when using `BinaryFormatter`, which means that *events* are serialized. Check your events: you should usually mark the backing delegate `[NonSerialized]`. In the case of field-like events, use `[field:NonSerialized]`. For example:

```
[field:NonSerialized]
public event EventHandler Foo;
```

or:

```
[NonSerialized]
private EventHandler foo;

public event EventHandler {
    add { foo += value; }
    remove { foo -= value; }
}
```

Comment: I haven't declared any events myself, but if delegates are serialized how do I prevent that?  Marking them with [NonSerialized] does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Your objects may not support serialization. If it is your custom objects mark them with [Serializable] attribute. Also you can read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx) article to know how implement your custom serialization process.

Comment: Yes I have marked my objects as [Serializable], the exception seems to be referring to Form1.  I don't want to serialize that.

Comment: Check if ArrayList has serialize attribute in it's definition, otherwise you'll have to write function that serialize your objects one by one.

Answer (score 0):

to Find All References, in Visual Studio, right click on that class (here the Main Form I guess) and then select Find All References (Ctrl + K,R)
Also for you to serialize something you need to have the [Serializable] attribute.
And I don't think you can serialize delegates.

Comment: Visual Studio returns 4 references, none from my code.  I have marked my classes as [Serializable].

Comment: do you get any InnerException while trying to serialize, can you paste you serialization code ?